# Cordova iOS Application Freezes When Date and Time Changed

Tags: iphone, angularjs, date, cordova, ios7

I have a strange issue with Cordova hybrid application built on AngularJS. I have a page which has date attributes and here my issue

- Go to any date time picker page in the application
- Minimize the application
- Goto system date&time settings
- Change date and time to a past date (future date is working fine)
- Launch back the application from background

It seems that the application freeze totally without an error message. I am testing the application on iPhone with iOS 7.x version. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar problem on android with the ionic framework, also dont know whats going on there

Comment: were you able to solve this?